# Magento - Payment method wont show on configuration

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, credit-card

I recently installed a payment method on magento 1.5 which is Camtech SecureXml payment gateway, but after the installation via Magento connect, its configuration panel on admin doesnt show.

Please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

-chris

Answer (score 0):

I found out that all local modules were disabled on app/etc/local.xml thats why installed modules were not working well. - Solved